# Terminal in OS X Lion: can't write åäö on remote machine

Tags: ssh, terminal, encoding, osx-lion

Can't type åäö on the command line when ssh'ing to a Debian machine. It works locally though.

Changing 'Declare terminal as' to 'xterm-color' doesn't seem to help, either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit /etc/ssh_config and comment out the line:

`SendEnv LANG LC_*`

This config change was introduced by Lion. See `man ssh_config` for more information on SendEnv.

Another alternative may be to modify the machines you're accessing, as described in grawity's answer.

A related thread on this topic: http://mod16.org/hurfdurf/?p=189

Comment: And if you're on macos Ventura:
edit the ssh config in your homefolder instead ( ~/.ssh/config ) and there add the line SendEnv LANG LC_*

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the remote machine has correct locale settings:

1. the value of `$LANG` (or `$LC_CTYPE`) should be an UTF-8 locale (`en_US.utf-8` for example); on Debian, the default value is set in `/etc/default/locale`
2. the chosen locale should be listed in *`locale -a`* – if not, edit `/etc/locale.gen` and run *`locale-gen`*.

Comment: This worked before Lion though, so I'm guessing the problem is on my side. But I'll double check.

Comment: locale-a gives me: locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory

Comment: locale-gen is not a command, only a manpage, not sure what to run.

Comment: @Jonatan: You might need the `locales` package on Debian.

Comment: Already installed: http://cl.ly/8zrl

Comment: @Jonatan: `locale-gen` is supposed to be run by root, and is in `/usr/sbin` because of that.

Comment: My `locales` was broken. Upgraded/reinstalled using `apt-get install locales` and then re-checked the locales using `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. After logging out and back in, the umlauts were working again.

Answer (score 2):

I had to *comment out* the line `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in `/etc/ssh_config` on a clean install of OS X Lion in order to get åäö to work on remote machines.

Just to make Google users happy: many of you probably want to configure this to make [Irssi](http://irssi.org) on remote servers work with special characters like åäö on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: That's what I meant to write, updated my answer, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Or even easier, you can uncheck the "Set locale environment variables on startup" setting in Terminal.app under Settings Windows > Settings Tab > Advanced and restart Terminal.app

Answer (score 0):

I have added:

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=POSIX
```

in `.bash_profile` located in my home folder.

Comment: If you meant this as an answer can you explain how this answers the question?  See the [faq] and [about] pages for more information about how this site works.  Thanks!