# Differences between en_US.utf8 and en_US.UTF-8?

Tags: environment-variables, utf-8, locale

I've had a terrible time getting zsh to play nicely with Debian Jessie, and I've come to the conclusion that my issues all stem from my system's locale. Running `locale`, I see

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

however `/etc/default/locale` contains `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` as does `/etc/environment`, and my `/etc/locale.gen` file only has `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` uncommented.

1. Why does `locale` report something (subtly) different than seemingly every other option on my system, and
2. How do I configure (fix) things to give "en_US.UTF-8" for every LC option when I run `locale`?

Answer (score 25):

The 'proper' name is `UTF-8`. However, Linux *glibc* will internally normalize the encoding name, by converting it to lowercase & removing most special characters, so both variants will work (as long as they don't escape to BSD systems).

Most of the time the `.utf8` suffix in $LANG comes from GNOME; afaik, this has been fixed in 3.18.

But as said above, both `utf8` and `UTF-8` will work the same way on Linux glibc – the problem comes from elsewhere. Since you didn't write what the problem *is*, here's a general checklist:

- Does `locale -a` (available locales) show either variant *at all?* I.e. have you *generated* (with `locale-gen`) the locales after editing locale.gen?
- Does the *terminal emulator's* environment have the same locale settings? Use `cat /proc/$(pidof xterm)/environ | tr \\0 \\n` to check the environment of another process.

  (Frequently people try to set locale envvars from their `~/.bashrc` or similar files, but environment variables do not propagate "upwards", so the end result.)
- What does `printf '\xe2\x99\xa5'` output? If it shows *one* box or question mark, it means the font doesn't have the necessary character. If it shows *three* garbage characters, it means your terminal doesn't have the right $LANG (or just doesn't support UTF-8).

Comment: Ahh, ok! Thanks! That illuminates things a little more for me. The problem that started this was an issue with zsh not properly rendering box-drawing characters; I just see a massive string of � replacement characters instead. Running `locale -a` only shows the lowercase variants, even after explicitly re-generating everything. The terminal emulator has the settings I would expect (i.e., en_US.UTF-8), and the output of printf shows me one little heart.

Comment: That rather sounds like the _source_ of these box-drawing characters is not actually UTF-8-encoded (perhaps your ~/.zshrc was saved in cp437?) Test the terminal emulator directly using `printf '┌┘'` and `printf '\xe2\x94\x8c\xe2\x94\x98\n'`, or perhaps `cat` a [demo file](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt).

Comment: I tried removing my ~/.zshrc and setting the appropriate options (`prompt adam2 8bit`) from the prompt directly so as to avoid any issues with the encoding of a settings file, but I still have the same issue. Which is particularly odd, because `cat`ting the demo file rendered perfectly---even the box-drawing characters at the end of the file!