# Unicode Characters not Displaying with ZSH

Tags: terminal, zsh, unicode

I'm accessing a server running Ubuntu from my Mac using Terminal. On the server, I recently switched from Bash to ZSH and now Unicode characters are not being displayed anymore, for example the folder that in bash was listed as `'芸能山城組'` is now being listed as `''$'\350\212\270\350\203\275\345\261\261\345\237\216\347\265\204'`.

I already set the locales in my .zshrc to `"en_US.UTF-8"` but that doesn't seem to change anything. It's also not the terminal font, because `echo -e '\u82B8'` outputs `芸` correctly.

Does anybody know what could be going wrong?

Comment: "being listed as …" – by what tool? `ls`? How exactly did you set the locale in `.zshrc`? What does `locale` print in Zsh? Does `locale -a` show `en_US.UTF-8` ([or `en_US.utf8`](https://superuser.com/a/999151/432690))? Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions describing a problem that went away when a typo was fixed (see the [OP's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1586300/432690)) are unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

It was, after all a typo in my locales.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I don't make a habit of doing that.  Especially when I didn't even realize the author self-answered their question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - The horse is dead.